# Sum of all Nodes Iteratively - Not Recursively - Without 'left' and 'right'

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration, binary-tree

I have this Binary Tree Structure:

```
# A Node is an object
# - value : Number
# - children : List of Nodes
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
```

I can easily sum the Nodes, recursively:

```
def sumNodesRec(root):
    sumOfNodes = 0
    for child in root.children:
        sumOfNodes += sumNodesRec(child)
    return root.value + sumOfNodes
```

Example Tree:

```
exampleTree = Node(1,[Node(2,[]),Node(3,[Node(4,[Node(5,[]),Node(6,[Node(7,[])])])])])

sumNodesRec(exampleTree)

> 28
```

However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to sum all the nodes iteratively. Normally, with a binary tree that has 'left' and 'right' in the definition, I can find the sum. But, this definition is tripping me up a bit when thinking about it iteratively.

Any help or explanation would be great. I'm trying to make sure I'm not always doing things recursively, so I'm trying to practice creating normally recursive functions as iterative types, instead.

Comment: How do you construct a tree? (sample input please?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we're talking iteration, this is a good use case for a *queue*.

```
total = 0

queue = [exampleTree]
while queue: 
    v = queue.pop(0)
    queue.extend(v.children)
    total += v.value

print(total)
28
```

This is a common idiom. Iterative graph traversal algorithms also work in this manner.

You can simulate stacks/queues using python's vanilla lists. Other (better) alternatives would be the `collections.deque` structure in the standard library. I should explicitly mention that its enque/deque operations are more efficient than what you'd expect from a vanilla list.

Comment: Why would you pop from the front of a `list`? Removing from the front of a `list` is O(*n*), so your algorithm is O(*n* ^2). If you absolutely needed to pop from the front, you should use an actual Python queue to maintain O(1) pop. Or, to keep things simple, since order doesn't matter here, just pop from the back instead of the front

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri You bring up a fair point, and I have a reason for that. I was not trying to provide the most efficient solution to OP. I am aware pop is O(n), which is why I mentioned the existence of other libraries better suited to this task (`deque`) though the reason I mentioned them wasn't made clear.

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri As said in the answer, You can use `collections.deque` to improve this. More specifically, you can use `popleft()` to improve popping from the front to `O(1)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry, didn't see the part about `collections.deque`, read too quickly

Answer (score 2):

Iteratively you can create a list, stack, queue, or other structure that can hold the items you run through. Put the root into it. Start going through the list, take an element and add its children into the list also. Add the value to the sum. Take next element and repeat. This way there’s no recursion but performance and memory usage may be worse.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the first answer:

```
def sumNodes(root):
    current = [root]
    nodeList = []
    while current:
        next_level = []
        for n in current:
            nodeList.append(n.value)
            next_level.extend(n.children)
        current = next_level
    return sum(nodeList)
```

Thank you! That explanation helped me think through it more clearly.

Comment: Not sure why our answers were downvoted, but I think this is a perfectly valid answer to your question.